# Lower transistor count CMOS implementations of XOR and/or XNOR with leakage current only for all static input combinations

Tags: logic-gates, cmos

I'm perfectly fine with the 10- and 12-transistor implementation(s), see e.g. en.wikipedia on [XOR gate CMOS implementation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate#CMOS).

There are variations of 6-transistor pass-gate XOR implementations  (suffering "level degradation").

Are there any implementations with less than six transistors(/lower area) that exhibit no more than leakage current from power supply as well as inputs for all static combinations of input values?

Comment: Are you asking for static-only solutions? Are you counting power supply leakage if it's on the inputs?

Comment: @W5VO: What definition of "non-static" logic do you suggest? Revisiting en.wikipedia on [static versus dynamic logic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_logic_(digital_electronics)#Static_versus_dynamic_logic), I guess so: I'm not looking for clocked/multiphase logic, domino logic or similar. I want none of power-to-power, power-to-input nor input-to-input currents beyond leakage currents with static input signals. (Call me a Mead-Conway guy.)